# Is there a way to send Push Notification with data payload manually?

Tags: android, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

Early I had a chance to test FCM service sending request through Postman

```
https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send
```

Header:

```
"key":"Content-Type","value":"application/json"
"key":"Authorization","value":"key=AIzaSyAA-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
```

Body:

```
{       
  "registration_ids":["token_id"],
  "data": {
    "title" : "title",
    "message" : "This is something you might be interested in"
  } 
}
```

But now I receive such kind of response

```
{
    "multicast_id": 6211560223995368844,
    "success": 0,
    "failure": 1,
    "canonical_ids": 0,
    "results": [
        {
            "error": "InvalidRegistration"
        }
    ]
}
```

Is there anybody could help me to fix my issue. I want to send Push Notification with Data payload and without Notification payload(I couldn't do it through Firebase console because it sends only not null Notification)

Comment: the issue is your `token_id` you are passing is no longer valid and you need a new one

Comment: Thanks, it was so easy